# How to link a Page with an anchor tag in WordPress

Tags: php

I want to link a Page with an anchor tag and send some data through a URL from another Page. I have made a page template and I tried to link to it, but it does not work. I can open the page by creating menu link but I can't open it directly using the  link.  My anchoring code is:

```
<p><?php echo $post_excerpt;?> <a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( array('id' => $id), home_url()."/fullpost/" ); ?>" style="color: #4e2011;">Read More...</a></p>
```

Now the problem is when I click on *Read More* the URL works fine, `id` is added to the URL, but I still end up on the same page, not my desired page. I have Googled several times about this problem but haven't found a solution.

Comment: what does it mean "I don't get my desired page"

Comment: What `fullpost.php` is meant to do?

Comment: No, that part will /fullpost/ only. Not fullpost.php. I have edited it. Thanks. @Rarst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was with my page settings. If someone wants to link a php file to another php file by anchor tag (a href="....") and wants to send some data through URL, he/she must has to make the targeted php file a page template. Like this

```
<?php 
/***
Template Name: Gallery
***/
```

Then he/she has to create a new page from the dashboard with this page template. Only after this process the link will work properly.

I didn't create the page from dashboard.